# On finding the region closer to the base of an isosceles triangle than the equal sides

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, contest-math, analytic-geometry, area

The question is posed as follows:

> Let $O(0,0), A(2,0), and B(1, \frac1{\sqrt3})$ be the vertices of a triangle. Let $R$ be the region consisting of of all those points $P$ inside $\triangle OAB$ which satisfy $$d(P, OA) \leq \min\{d(P, OB), d(P,AB)\}$$ where $d$ denotes the distance from the point to the corresponding line. Sketch the region $R$ and find its area.

My solution is as follows:

Firstly, we note that $\triangle OAB$ is an isosceles one with $|OA| = |BA|$. So, our region will be symmertric with respect to the median through $A$.

Now, we divide $R$ into infinitesimal regions (strips) along the $X$ axis. The line $OB$ is one such strip itself as every point on it is at a distance 0 from $OB$ and is at most also at a distance $0$ from $OA$ or $AB$. Taking the next strip, right "above" $OB$, this is essentially a slightly "shorter" strip as we must remove the point of its intersection with either side where the distance would be $0$ vs $\epsilon > 0$ to the base. Similarly, the strips will form some sort of shape that will reduce in length until we reach a point where (by symmetry), all the sides are equidistant. The shape will be a triangle, as of course we have seen the base is $OB$ (a line) and as we move up, the sides get closer to the median of this region linearly.

We may find the third vertex, say, $C$ of $R$ by the fact that it is the incenter of $\triangle OAB$, or by our earlier reasoning (or by any other valid method) that $C(c_x, c_y)$ is equidistant from $OA$ and $OB$ to get $C \equiv (1, 2-\sqrt 3)$. It is now trivial to draw the graph and find the area.

$\mathbf{My\ problem}$: is that *it is not at all **mathematically rigorous*** as a proof and so I would appreciate help in making it as such.  (or even another, slicker solution would be cool).

This is tagged with `contest-math` as it appeared in JEE 1997(2). JEE is an Indian entrance examination for the system of Indian Institutes of Technology for undergraduate courses.

---

Edit: There is a good alternate answer to this question due to @RossMillikan and his comments under this question. I would like to see if it is possible to flesh out my own answer to make it viable also. Thank you to all participants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the isosceles triangle in the usual orientation, sitting on the base.  If you think about points near one of the base angles of the triangles, they will be closer to the base than one of the equal sides if they are below the bisector of the base angle.  The area closer to be base is inside the inner triangle in the figure below.

[image]

Comment: The equal sides should be shorter than the base! Nor do I understand your labelling. But, of course you are right that the area is the triangle formed by base and incentre (although you don't actually mention that it is the incentre).

Comment: @almagest:  why should be equal sides be shorter than the base?  Isosceles triangles can be either way.  That doesn't change anything-just bisect the base angles and extend the bisectors until they meet.  Yes, this is the incenter, but that is not important.

Comment: Yes, but you are given the coordinates! So you know the lengths. I agree it makes no difference, but it makes the diagram look bizarrely bad!

Comment: @almagest:  OK, fixed.  I don't know how to get GeoGebra to give me a window with longer spaces between the numbers, so the coordinates are wrong, but the shape is about right

Comment: Bravo! Of course, my hand-drawn diagrams are often far worse, and diagrams don't need to be remotely accurate to be helpful. But there is something bizarre about a beautiful machine-drawn diagram which is the wrong shape. The OP started by referring to OA=OB, which made his approach not just long-winded but hard to follow!

Comment: I think this is a slicker way to do it but do you think it is mathematically rigorous? If not could you explain how it could be made so?

Comment: This is rigorous.  The points inside an angle (one of the base angles) closer to one side than the other are the ones on the proper side of the bisector.  Then you take the intersection of the regions for the two angles.  It takes a bit of fleshing out.  You can divide the isosceles triangle with the centerline and point out that the points on the left of the centerline are closer to the left side than the right, so we only need to consider the left side and the base for them, for example.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Before I mark your answer I'd like to see if you or anyone else could help me flesh out my own attempt if possible. Thanks again.